# Error: downloads_path_provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I m using [This package](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider) to get download path in android which work well.
By using this Package I get `/storage/emulated/0/Download` which I want.

Problem: When I ran `flutter run --release` it throws an error.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM J700F in release mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':downloads_path_provider:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Sandeep Sharma\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\56f020e9c27d6a807cc1a74760f6e28d\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVa
riationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\Sandeep Sharma\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\56f020e9c27d6a807cc1a74760f6e28d\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcInd
ex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 34s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     158.0s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
```

if This can't be solved then suggest being how to get this path `/storage/emulated/0/Download` or another way around.

Update: I just saw [Repo of Downloads_path_provider](https://github.com/nplaceit/downloads_path_provider) which says

> This plugin has lots of inconsistencies and should no longer be used. Feel free to fork and tweak it.

what should I use to get this path `/storage/emulated/0/Download`.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this works in debug mode?

Comment: yes. it works in debug mode.

Comment: do you want internal or external storage path?

Comment: Internal would be better if internal doesn't work then of course external.

Comment: Same happened with me

Answer (score 2):

instead use the [ext_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage) plugin:

```
ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

I had the same issue and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the official package provided by the flutter known as [path_provide](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) and use the `getDownloadsDirectory()` method to get the path.

Comment: I have already tried this. This is not for android `Unsupported operation: Functionality only available on macOS`